# Salt custom grains and Python version

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, salt-stack

I have grains in `/srv/salt/_grains` which are written using `Python2.7` for `Ubuntu 14.04` environment. We started using `Ubuntu 18.04` and want to use the same Salt-Master for both environments. The problem is that the newer environment can only understand `Python3`.

Is there a way to specify different grains for different environment?

Versions:

```
salt-minion 2016.3.8 (Boron)  -- Ubuntu 14.04
salt-minion 2017.7.4 (Nitrogen)  -- Ubuntu 18.04
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can design it

by **env** https://fabianlee.org/2016/10/05/saltstack-creating-a-custom-grain-using-python/

**envtypegrain.py**

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import socket
import logging
log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def environment():

    hostname = socket.gethostname().upper()
    log.debug("envtypegrain hostname: " + hostname)

    if "-DEV" in hostname:
        return {'envtype':'dev'}
    elif "-TEST" in hostname:
        return {'envtype':'test'}
    elif "-PROD" in hostname:
        return {'envtype':'prod'}
    else:
        return {'envtype':'n/a'}



if __name__ == "__main__":
    print environment()
```

Or **by groups** https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/targeting/

Or **define os** https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/topics/tutorials/states_pt3.html#using-grains-in-sls-modules

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, these guides are for custom state files management? The problem I have is that other environment doesn't recognise the language in `_grains` due to version differences. Maybe it's possible to specify which `_grain` configuration it should use in the `role` itself?

Comment: I need the error to understand how to debug it. Eg .items() is solvable for both py2&3. Anyway, I think you can't escape whithout writing another grains for py3. And salt version is also important: https://github.com/saltstack/salt/issues/47461